# Event change some text on scroll X distance

Tags: blazor

i'm trying to get some text to change as the user scrolls down currently i'm using @onmouseover on the element below it to change it. However this isn't an ideal solution. I don't know if it will work for mobile for example. Also if someone uses the browser slider it won't work.

Does anyone know how I can update it based on the user scrolling down the webpage X distance say 50vh? I'm using Blazor Client if its relevant.

Comment: That can only be solved by JS using the `onscroll` event on `window` or a specific element

Comment: @aguafrommars So there is no C# implementation currently then :(

Comment: no, there isn't